# Create a Windows executable from a .bat, .exe and some other data files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an application app.exe that must be called with the following syntax:

```
 app.exe -c COM1 <data file>
```

I also have a data file, named data.dat. So I created a launch.bat script:

```
app.exe -c COM1 data.dat
```

I want to create a **single executable** app_launcher.exe that should automatically extract the three files in a temporary directory and automatically launch the launch.bat script. I want the three files to be deleted automatically when the app.exe finishes.

Which technology should I use?

Comment: Well you could search the web for **Bat to exe**.  You could also use IEXPRESS which is included with windows.

Comment: Scrap the .bat file. Simply embed *app.exe* and *data file* as binary resources, extract them on startup using the `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` flag (see [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx)), and launch the extracted *app.exe* by calling [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx).

Comment: @Squashman. Neither of those solutions allows to clean up after executing *app.exe*.

Comment: @IInspectable, I beg to differ. Bat to exe programs usually dump all the files into a temp folder and then executes the batch file and then deletes all the files it has extracted.  I have experience with this and have done it before.  We have a thread on Dostips.com about using IEXPRESS as well.

Answer (score 1):

I devised an interesting method to combine several text files plus one binary file into a Batch file, that can extract and manipulate they in any desired way. The trick consists in combine all files in the Batch file and then read its contents via a block of commands with its input redirected to the Batch file, so different sections of itself can be separately read. For example:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

< "%~F0" (

   rem Skip this Batch code: 20 lines
   for /L %%i in (1,1,20) do set /P =

   rem Copy the data file: 2 lines
   (for /L %%i in (1,1,2) do (
      set /P "line="
      echo !line!
   )) > data.txt

   rem Copy the rest of this file into an .exe
   findstr "^" > theProgram.exe

)

goto :EOF
These are the lines
of the data file
... the binary code of the .exe file ...
... must be placed here ...
```

To generate the working Batch file, combine this base code with the binary .exe file this way:

```
copy base.bat +theProgram.exe /B working.bat /B
```

However, this method is limited by the capabilities of `findstr.exe` command to read binary data, so it may or may not work depending on the contents of the binary file.

In order to fix this point, I wrote a very simple auxiliary .exe program that just read bytes from a redirected file handle and output they to Stdout. Using this program, called ReadFile.exe, is possible to embed *any binary file* into a Batch file and extract it. This is the output of an example of this method using findstr.exe file as the example binary file:

```
C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\ASMB\test> copy base.bat +findstr.exe /B working.bat /B

base.bat
findstr.exe
        1 archivo(s) copiado(s).

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\ASMB\test> ren findstr.exe findstr2.exe

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\ASMB\test> working

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\ASMB\test> fc /B findstr.exe findstr2.exe
Comparando archivos findstr.exe y FINDSTR2.EXE
FC: no se han encontrado diferencias
```

To get ReadFile.exe auxiliary file, download and execute this Batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create ReadFile.exe auxiliary program
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

echo Creating ReadFile.exe file, please wait...
rem Code modified based on :genchr subroutine
type nul > t.tmp
set "options=/d compress=off /d reserveperdatablocksize=26"
(for /F %%a in ('more +49 "%~F0"') do (
   set input=%%a
   set i=0
   for /L %%I in (0,2,120) do for %%i in (!i!) do if "!input:~%%i,1!" neq "" (
      set hex=!input:~%%i,2!
      set /A i+=2
      if "!hex:~0,1!" neq "[" (
         set /A chr=0x!hex!
         if not exist !chr!.chr call :genchr !chr!
         type !chr!.chr
      ) else (
         for /L %%J in (1,1,5) do for %%i in (!i!) do if "!input:~%%i,1!" neq "]" (
            set "hex=!hex!!input:~%%i,1!"
            set /A i+=1
         )
         if not exist 0.chr call :genchr 0
         for /L %%J in (1,1,!hex:~1!) do type 0.chr
         set /A i+=1
      )
   )
)) > ReadFile.exe
del *.chr t.tmp temp.tmp
exit /B


:genchr
REM This code creates one single byte. Parameter: int
REM Teamwork of carlos, penpen, aGerman, dbenham
REM Tested under Win2000, XP, Win7, Win8
if %~1 neq 26 (
   makecab %options% /d reserveperfoldersize=%~1 t.tmp %~1.chr > nul
   type %~1.chr | ( (for /l %%N in (1,1,38) do pause)>nul & findstr "^" > temp.tmp )
   >nul copy /y temp.tmp /a %~1.chr /b
) else (
   copy /y nul + nul /a 26.chr /a >nul
)
exit /B


4d5a900003[3]04[3]ffff[2]b8[7]40[35]b0[3]0e1fba0e00b409cd21b8014ccd21546869732070726f6772616d2063616e6e6f742062
652072756e20696e20444f53206d6f64652e0d0d0a24[7]55917b8611f015d511f015d511f015d59fef06d51bf015d5edd007d513f015d5
5269636811f015d5[8]5045[2]4c01020069629657[8]e0000f010b01050c0002[3]02[7]10[3]10[3]20[4]40[2]10[3]02[2]04[7]04[8]
30[3]02[6]03[5]10[2]10[4]10[2]10[6]10[11]2020[2]28[84]20[2]20[27]2e74657874[3]4801[3]10[3]02[3]02[14]20[2]602e
7264617461[2]dc[4]20[3]02[3]04[14]40[2]40[8]e806[3]50e81301[2]558bec83c4ece8da[3]e8f9[3]c745ec[4]0fb606460ac00f
84b3[3]2c30040af7d850e8f0[3]8945fcb8f5ffffff50e8e2[3]8945f8e8c4[3]0fb6064633db0ac00f8483[3]eb038a06463c30720e3c
39770a2c308d1c9b8d1c58ebebe8aa[3]85c074688bd068[2]04006a0052e8a3[3]85c074558bf88bcb0bc97505b9[2]040081f9[2]0400
7605b9[2]04006a008d45f4505157ff75fce87b[3]6a008d45f050ff75f457ff75f8e86f[3]8b45f00145ec394df472090bdb74b72b5df4
75b28b45ecc9c3b8ffffffffc9c3cccccce84d[3]8bf08a06463c2275098a06463c2275f9eb0c8a06463c20740484c075f54ec38a06463c
2074f94ec3ccff2518204000ff2500204000ff2504204000ff2508204000ff250c204000ff2510204000ff25142040[185]7620[2]8820[2]
9820[2]a420[2]b020[2]bc20[2]6820[6]4820[10]ce20[3]20[22]7620[2]8820[2]9820[2]a420[2]b020[2]bc20[2]6820[6]9b0045
78697450726f6365737300560147657450726f6365737348656170[2]6a0147657453746448616e646c65[2]bd0148656170416c6c6f63
003d025265616446696c65[2]f702577269746546696c6500e600476574436f6d6d616e644c696e6541006b65726e656c33322e646c6c[294]
```

This is the help of ReadFile.exe:

```
Read bytes from a redirected input file handle and output they to StdOut.

ReadFile handle numOfBytes

If numOfBytes is zero, read all bytes from current FP position until EOF.

At end, the number of output bytes is returned in ERRORLEVEL.

An example of this program is shown at:
http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6236&p=42161#p42161
```

Note that ReadFile can read a certain number of bytes; this means that using it, and given the proper sizes, it is possible to embed *several binary files* in the same Batch file! **`;)`**